# fancyhdr resets geometry to adjust header heights?

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

I use two pagestyles `fancy` for the default header and `plain` for headers on chapter pages. These headers should have completely different heights, however, it looks like latex adjusts both header heights to the maximum and tries to keep header height constant throughout the whole document. Why is that, and how can I disable this "feature"?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \textcolor{black}{\llap{%
      \colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\thepage}}}}}

\fancyhead[L]{%
    \textcolor{black}{\rlap{%
        \colorbox{yellow}{\leftmark}}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}%
\fancyhead[R]{%
    \textcolor{black}{\rlap{%
        \hspace{-9\marginparsep}%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{14pt}
        \colorbox{yellow}{%
            \makebox(23,93)[cb]{\Huge\textbf{\thechapter.}}}%       
      }}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
text
\newpage
\section{bar}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are aware that `fancyhdr` complains about the head height? You gave `16pt`, but it requests `122pt`

Comment: Normally, no header is included on `plain` pages. You would create the 'header' for the chapter as part of the `\chapter` formatting rather than as part of a header. I think this is the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought that was the point of the question ;).

Comment: Using \raisebox fixes everything except the line drawn below the header, which stays in the same place regardless.

Comment: a trick `\fancyfoot[L]{%
\global\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}%.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pagestyle `plain` is used for more than just the first page in a chapter, you are better off overlaying a header directly.  Tikz is one option.  Everypage is another (`\AddThispageHook`).  You could create a `\mychapter` macro to simplify the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \textcolor{black}{\llap{{%
      \colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\thepage}}}}}}

\fancyhead[L]{%
    \textcolor{black}{\rlap{%
        \colorbox{yellow}{\leftmark}}}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{foo}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) +(1in+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth-9\marginparsep,0pt)
  node[below right,inner sep=14pt,fill=yellow]
    {\makebox(23,93)[cb]{\Huge\textbf{\thechapter.}}};
\draw (current page.north west) ++(1in+\oddsidemargin,-121pt) -- +(\textwidth,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

text
\newpage
\section{bar}
text
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter header]

Here is a solution using everypage.  The "cursor" is located at (1in,-1in) relative to the upper left corner and must not be moved.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{everypage}

\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \textcolor{black}{\llap{{%
      \colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\thepage}}}}}}

\fancyhead[L]{%
    \textcolor{black}{\rlap{%
        \colorbox{yellow}{\leftmark}}}}

\newcommand{\chapterhead}{\fboxsep=14pt\relax% local to header
  \raisebox{\dimexpr 1in-109pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \oddsidemargin+\textwidth-9\marginparsep}%
       \colorbox{yellow}{%
         \makebox(23,93)[cb]{\Huge\textbf{\thechapter.}}}}%       
    \rlap{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}\rule[-16pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{foo}
\AddThispageHook{\chapterhead}

text
\newpage
\section{bar}
text
\end{document}
```

[image: another chapter header]

Comment: +1 for offering two methods. Tikz worked for me, however, only without the calculations in `path` and `draw` (in path, `+(16cm,0pt)` will do).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an additional suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr`. Then you can define a new page style for the chapter pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\color{black}}

\lefoot*{\smash{\llap{\colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\pagemark}}}}}
\rofoot*{\smash{\rlap{\colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\pagemark}}}}}

\ohead{\colorbox{yellow}{\leftmark}}

% Declare new layers and a new page style for the first page of a chapter
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{chapterfirstpage}{%
  chapternumber,chapternumberline,%
  plain.scrheadings.foot.odd,plain.scrheadings.foot.oneside%
}
\DeclareNewLayer[
   background,
   head,
   align=t,
   voffset=0pt,
   height=93pt,
   contents={%
      \parbox[b][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{14pt}%
          \hfill\rlap{\colorbox{yellow}{%
              \makebox(23,93)[cb]{\Huge\textbf{\thechapter.}}}}%
           \hspace*{9\marginparsep}}}
]{chapternumber}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=plain.scrheadings.head.below.line,
  voffset=107pt,
  addvoffset=-\ht\strutbox,
  contents=\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
]{chapternumberline}

% use page style chapterfirstpage instead plain on the first page of a chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{chapterfirstpage}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\Blindtext
\section{bar}
\blindtext
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[3]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if there are also unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\color{black}}

\lefoot*{\smash{\llap{\colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\pagemark}}}}}
\rofoot*{\smash{\rlap{\colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\pagemark}}}}}

\ohead{\colorbox{yellow}{\leftmark}}

% Declare new layers and a new page style for the first page of a chapter
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{chapterfirstpage}{%
  chapternumber,chapternumberline,%
  plain.scrheadings.foot.odd,plain.scrheadings.foot.oneside%
}
\DeclareNewLayer[
   background,
   head,
   align=t,
   voffset=0pt,
   height=93pt,
   contents={%
      \parbox[b][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{14pt}%
          \hfill\rlap{\colorbox{yellow}{%
              \makebox(23,93)[cb]{\Huge\textbf{\thechapter.}}}}%
           \hspace*{9\marginparsep}}}
]{chapternumber}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=plain.scrheadings.head.below.line,
  voffset=107pt,
  addvoffset=-\ht\strutbox,
  contents=\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
]{chapternumberline}

\newcommand\chapternumberon{%
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{chapterfirstpage}{chapternumber}{}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{chapterfirstpage}{chapternumber,chapternumberline}}%
}
\newcommand\chapternumberoff{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{chapterfirstpage}{chapternumber,chapternumberline}}

% use page style chapterfirstpage instead plain on the first page of a chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{chapterfirstpage}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapternumberoff
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\chapternumberon
\chapter{foo}
\Blindtext
\section{bar}
\blindtext
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[3]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]