# Header margin differing from the text margin

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I would like to place my page number above the marginside note area. Therefore, the margin at header will be different from the text area. 
I capture a page from *Concepts in Thermal Physics* by Blundel as an example. 
[image]
How to specify the position of the header?

Note: I used `twoside` in the documentclass.

Comment: To answer your question, I would use everypage to implement the header directly (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268692/fancyhdr-resets-geometry-to-adjust-header-heights/268720?s=3|0.5102#268720).  from the picture I would suggest using paracol instead, reserving one column for figures.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320065/marginpar-start-at-top-of-page/320077?s=9|0.0805#320077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do with `titleps`, a companion package to  `titlesec`:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}

    \usepackage[outer=0.33\paperwidth, marginparwidth=0.25\paperwidth, marginparsep=5mm, showframe ]{geometry}
    \usepackage[pagestyles, indentafter]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum, marginnote}
    \renewcommand\marginfont{\footnotesize}
    \renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{\raggedright}
    \newpagestyle{marginhead}{%

    \sethead[\footnotesize\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax][l]{\thepage\quad\textit{\chaptertitle}}}][][]%
    {}{}{\footnotesize\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax][r]{\textit{\sectiontitle}\quad\thepage}}}
    }

    \pagestyle{marginhead}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{4}\setcounter{section}{1}

    \section{The thermodynamic limit}

    \lipsum[2]
    More text more text more text more text \marginnote{This header style begins at the same point as margin paragraphs}. More text more text more text more text.More text more text more text more text. More text more text more text more text.

    \lipsum


    \section{The Next Section}
    It also gets really messed up for two-sided documents, if the left and right margin are set to different values. Moving only section text would alleviate this problem.

    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! There is an extra question: what's the difference or the same between `\usepackage{sidenote}` and `\usepackage{marginnote}`

Comment: I suppose you mean `sidenotes`.  The latter seems to have more possibilities, such as loading floats (I never had to use it). It requires `marginnote`.